# MacOS Activity Monitor commands (cached files) in Python

Tags: python, macos, psutil, activity-monitor

The goal of the script is to generate logs that monitor a macOS machines RAM, CPU, Disk and Network Statistics.

I'm successfully able to display some memory stats using psutil.virtual_memory() or the vm_stat command in terminal.

psutil - https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

However I would like to specifically display the 'cached files' stat shown in Activity Monitor (below).

[image: macOS activity monitor cached files]

I don't want to do this a ghetto way like clearing the cache and then measuring the available RAM before and after and subtracting.

Here's what what I'm playing with:

```
import psutil

mem = str(psutil.virtual_memory())
mem = mem.replace(',', '')
mem = mem.split()

mem_total = mem[0].split("=")
mem_total = mem_total[1]
mem_total = round(int(mem_total)/1024**3, ndigits=1)

mem_used = mem[3].split("=")
mem_used = mem_used[1]
mem_used = round(int(mem_used)/1024**3, ndigits=1)

mem_free = mem[4].split("=")
mem_free = mem_free[1]
mem_free = round(int(mem_free)/1024**3, ndigits=1)

print(mem_total)
print(mem_used)
print(mem_free)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I programmed a tool exactly like this a little while ago called [`Tocco`](https://github.com/simple-touch/Tocco), which I would encourage you to check out its code on Github. It also uses [`psutil`](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) to pull OSX system information. Here is the specific part of the code you are asking for, using [`psutil.virtual_memory()`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.virtual_memory):

```py
import psutil

def humansize(nbytes):
    """ Appends prefix to bytes for human readability. """

    suffixes = ["B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB"]
    i = 0
    while nbytes >= 1024 and i < len(suffixes) - 1:
        nbytes /= 1024.0
        i += 1
    f = ("%.2f" % nbytes).rstrip("0").rstrip(".")
    return "%s %s" % (f, suffixes[i])

mem = psutil.virtual_memory()

print(humansize(mem.used))
print(humansize(mem.free))
print(humansize(mem.active))
print(humansize(mem.inactive))
print(humansize(mem.wired))
```

Outputs:

```
4.06 GB
16.57 MB
2.02 GB
1.95 GB
2.04 GB
```

Comment: Thanks that looks awesome, very useful. Although it doesn't seem to display "Cached Files", which is ideally what I was looking for.